# Problem recompiling using make command in ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu-10.10, ns2

I m trying to modify some C++ files in ns2 and then recompile using make command. Although new .o file is created after make, the output is similar to that of previous C++ file (before modifying). can someone suggest what may be the reason behind it.

Comment: Did you recompile and link the app that is using the .o file?

Comment: yes, actually i m trying to simulate a routing protocol, the parameter i.e. name of the protocol is entered in a tcl file which is run. i modified the spin.cc file which generated the spin.o file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're running your newly built ns2 executable -- if you just type `ns2`, you'll get the installed ns2 binary on the system, which you haven't changed (unless you do a `make install` and even then it might install it in a different place, leaving the old one where it is).

Generally you'll need to run `./ns2` if you want to make sure you get the executable in the current directory (which is *probably* the one you just built, but check the Makefile and the date on the executable to be more sure.)

Answer (score 0):

This usually means you're not compiling what you think you are.  Try renaming your source file and see if make still "compiles" it (it shouldn't).   Alternatively, make sure you're saving your changes from your editor.

Comment: thanks ethan for the suggestion. i renamed the source file spin.cc to spin1.cc and it was giving error  make: * No rule to make target `spin/spin.o', needed by `ns'.  Stop.

Comment: next i changed the makefile (changed spin.o to spin1.o here) and did make. the spin1.o file is created, simulation runs but the output is the same as previous one.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the build time dependencies, you would

```
sudo apt-get build-dep ns2
```

Proceed to get the sources (46Mb approx) and compile

```
mkdir $HOME/ns2work
cd $HOME/ns2work
apt-get source ns2 --compile
```

You'd be done. (it built ns2, ns2-doc and ns2-examples in 2'55" on my workstation). Inside the source directory you can edit the source and run 'make' or debuild to rebuild using your changes.

When using this method (and debuild) **you will end up with .deb files in mkdir $HOME/ns2work** so you can actually install it cleanly (on several machines if you want)

Good luck